# What parameter type should I use for contract methods that specify floating point amounts?

Tags: solidity, ether, floating-point

In my dApp the user sets the entry fee for the game they are creating. The entry fee for games will usually be between $5 USD and $50 USD. What unit should I use for the contract method that accepts payment for the game (i.e. - the type to preface the relevant method parameter with)? Should I use: wei, gwei, eth, etc.?

Also, what Solidity type should I use internally in my contract that does a fair number of numeric calculations when it comes time to pay the players? I assume a fixed point type like uint* is not a good fit? I'm asking this question both for storage and memory variables.

I assume for percentages I can just use *uint* and divide by 100 internally?  But I'm asking the above questions for parameters that will be receiving floating point numbers generally.

Comment: It's reasonable to use a fixed number of decimals (like `10^18` wei being `1` ether), or you can use an explicit rational number with a separate numerator and denominator (e.g. `(7, 100)` means 0.07). The latter is the approach taken here: https://programtheblockchain.com/posts/2018/02/27/writing-a-token-market-contract/.

Comment: For your first question, you probably want to accept an amount in wei, and the appropriate type for the parameter is `uint256`.

Comment: @smarx Thanks.  Now all I have to do is find a reliable API to give me a quote in USD for Eth, and another one to convert between one fiat currency and another so I can show the user a friendly monetary value.

Answer (score 1):

*In my opinion,* it is preferable to adapt to the EVM's use of integers where possible. It is nearly always possible.

For example, here is a simple pattern for handling a percentage with two high-precision integers (one could be an exchange rate and the other a transaction volume). First, convert each input to an 18-decimal integer. So 1.0 would be 1 * 10 ** 18. 87% is 0.870,000,000,000,000,000, or as an integer 870000000000000000.

When you multiply two large integers together you get an even larger integer since ( 10 ** 18 ) * ( 10 ** 18 ) is 10 ** 36. You will have the correct significant digits and you just need to adjust the decimal position for correct *interpretation*.

Consider this pattern:

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.6;

contract Precision {
    
    uint constant PRECISION = 10 ** 18;
    uint constant demonstrateRatio = 87 * 10 ** 16;
    
    function percentOf(uint baseValue) public pure returns(uint result) {
        return ( baseValue * demonstrateRatio ) / PRECISION;
    }
}
```

**Tip: Always multiply before dividing to avoid loss of precision.**

For example, rewrite the following:

`x = ( a / b ) * PRECISION`

as

`x = ( a * PRECISION ) / b`

This is because 100/200 = 0 (with truncation) and 0 * PRECISION = 0. On the other hand, (100 * PRECISION) / 200 gives a non-zero result that can be returned after adjusting the decimal position with  `/ PRECISION`.

If you want correct rounding, you can add 5 to the nominator before dividing which will either round up (correctly) or truncate the result (correctly).

`x = ( a * PRECISION + 5 ) / b`

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Solidity does not support floating point variables because they are harder to be deterministic with and are not the most secure. The most common version of decimals is to have a uint that is not a single ETH or USD, but 1/10^18th of one.

Answer (score 0):

You may use [ABDK Math 64.64](https://github.com/abdk-consulting/abdk-libraries-solidity/blob/master/ABDKMath64x64.sol) library.  It operates with binary fixed point numbers (64 binary digits after dot) and contains all basic math operations.  It uses `int128` type to represent fixed point number.